# How to move a scrollbar together with the left position of its <div> (possibly with React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, scrollbar, css-position

I have an horizontal slider with lots of "cards".

[image: horizontal slider]

The JS code that defines its CSS is as follows:

```
    cardCarouselSlider: {
      zIndex: 0,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      width: 300 * cardsNumber,
      height: 200,
      position: 'absolute',
      left: (targetedPlanIndex >= 0)
        ? -281 * targetedPlanIndex + 40
        : -281 * (targetedPlanIndex + 1) + 40,
      transition: 'left 0.5s ease',
    },
```

As the value of `left` shows, I can have the slider slide horizontally by changing the value of `targetedPlanIndex`.

However, my customer wants to have also a scrollbar (you see it in the image) to be able to scroll rapidly between the cards.

Problem is: when I increase `targetedPlanIndex`, the slider scrolls to the left, but the scrollbar remains always glued to its start position. See next image, where the index was increased by 1:

[image: horizontal slider - index increased]

I'd like to see the scrollbar slide to the right as the slider goes left, as it would happen if I used the scrollbar to move the slider (see third image).

[image: scrolling with the scrollbar]

Any idea how I could do this?

My page is built with React, so basically I believe I am willing to attach some `scroll` event listener to my slider div, and not to the whole `document`. After that, there should be some `useScrollPosition` hook to tinker with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pursuing this quest for another couple of days, I haven't been able to find examples of React hooks that are able to detect/manage the scroll of individual components in page, let alone horizontal scroll.

I have solved my problem by leaving CSS aside and putting in place a JS/DOM-based solution, catering to the Element methods that control [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll).

These React solutions are all based on using a [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook tied to the page Element that is to be controlled, and accessing its methods through the `current` property of the reference.

The main drawback of these solutions is that (regardless of what the standards seem to promise) I cannot exploit CSS easing functions to implement a smooth scroll transition: for that I was forced to use a `setInterval`/`setTimeout` solution to perform many partial scrolls of my component.